# LinkedIn import requests excessive privileges

Tags: support, jobs, linkedin

When importing a LinkedIn profile, I'm asked to approve access to

- YOUR PROFILE OVERVIEW (fine)
- YOUR FULL PROFILE (makes sense)
- YOUR CONNECTIONS (hang on a minute...)
- INVITATIONS AND MESSAGES (whoa there!!)

I'm uneasy about allowing SE access to my list of connections, and access to messages is a definite 'no way'. My LinkedIn messages are private.

What exactly does the import feature do with the connections, invitations and messages data? If the answer is 'nothing', could it be modified so that access to this data is not requested at all?

Comment: According to the other post, the last permission is just intended to be for write access to facilitate the completely optional activity of sending Careers invites to your connections, but I don't use LinkedIn, so I haven't experienced how it's presented firsthand. In either case, it would be nice if you could say "I don't intend to ever do that, request lesser access."

Comment: This was on the mobile site, which might present the permissions differently (and unnervingly).